# Understanding variable scope in my program

Tags: java, variables, scope

I am a newbie at programming and have successfully been using this site to learn and overcome obstacles. Before I bring my new question forward, let me first thank all those who have been such a great help.

I am working on my first project and have solved the little problem that was preventing the program to run. However, the solution to the problem was found by guess and I would very much like to know why. It should be a variable scope issue. here is a snippet of the program?

```
public class AlladinLamp {    

JMenuBar jmBar;
JComboBox runners, raceDiv, days, months;       
JButton horseList, ok, clear;
JTextField[] jtxt;
JTextField raceName;
JTextArea message;
String status; 
JDialog dialog;
JPanel table, data, jp, middle;
JFrame jfr;     
String[] hNam ;                                    // string array holding horse names
int[] hNum, hVal;
int reducedFNH, id, vp, day, month, fnh, dv;       // fnh is the number of horses in the
                                                      race                  

Processes processes;
GridBagLayout gbLayout;  
GridBagConstraints gbc;  

...

public AlladinLamp()
{
 ...

public ActionListener horseListActionListener = new ActionListener()
{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
  {
       Toolkit myKit = dialog.getToolkit();
       Dimension dialSize = myKit.getScreenSize();
       dialog.setLocation( dialSize.width/2, dialSize.height/4 );
       dialog.setSize( 260, 380 );
       dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );       

       jp.setLayout( gbLayout );  
       jtxt = new JTextField[ fnh ];            <--- array of textfields for the horse                                                                                                                 names

       JLabel label;
       String str;
       for( int i = 0; i < fnh; i++ )
       {                   
          gbc.gridx = 0;
          gbc.gridy = i;           
          str = new Integer( i+1 ) + ".";                  
          label = new JLabel( str ); 
          jp.add( label, gbc );         

          gbc.gridx = 1;
          gbc.gridy = i;
          gbc.ipady = 4;
          gbc.insets = new Insets(4,0,0,0);
          jtxt[i] = new JTextField(15);  
          jp.add( jtxt[i], gbc );               
       }
       JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();        
       ok = new JButton( "OK" );       
       ok.addActionListener( okActionListener );           
       buttonPanel.add( ok ); 
       clear = new JButton ( "CLEAR" );        
       clear.addActionListener( clearActionListener );   

       buttonPanel.add( clear );       
       JScrollPane jscr = new JScrollPane( jp );  
       dialog.add( jscr, BorderLayout.CENTER ); 
       dialog.add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH ); 
       dialog.setVisible( true );
   }
};
```

...

```
public ActionListener okActionListener = new ActionListener()
{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
  {       
    hNam = new String[ fnh ];
    hNum = new int[ fnh ];
    hVal = new int[ fnh ];  
    for( int i = 0; i < fnh; i++ )
    {               
      hNam[i] = jtxt[i].getText();             
      hNum[i] = reduce( i + 1 );       
      hVal[i] = nameValue( hNam[i] );   
    }
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString(hNam) );
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString(hVal) );
    setID( hNam );                              
   dialog.setVisible( false );       
  }
};
```

...

The program is basically a GUi that accepts several kinds of input. The listener of the horselist button builds a jDialog that accepts input of names of horse names in a race.

The listener for the OK button retrieves those names from the textfields and stores them in the hNam array. Now, when I move the first tthree lines initializing hNam, hVal and hNum  to within the constructor, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception stemming from the next statement `hNam[i] = jtxt[i].getText();`

Why is that so???

Comment: This has nothing to do with variable scope. The error you are seeing means that either `jtxt` or `hNam` is less than `i-1` elements long are you are exceeding their bounds.

Comment: how do you initialize `fnh`? Because you use it but never initialize it (in this part of code at least.

Comment: The array holding the textfields for the horse names is initialized in the first listener as previously indicated. Neither jtxt nor hnam is less than i-1 elements as also indicated in the program...  ?

Comment: If `fnh > jtxt[]` you'll obtain ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception then compare the value of `fnh` when you intialize `jtxt[]` with the value of `fnh` when you start your `for`